# Is common-law status compulsory/involuntary in Canada or optional/voluntary?

Tags: canada, taxes, common-law-marriage

Would a couple have to specifically declare themselves or apply for common-law status, or is it implicitly bestowed?

For example, if one passes away, can the other claim common law status without a written indication from the deceased? Can the two file taxes separately, or must they file together?

Answer (score 2):

Taxes in Canada, unlike the US and some other jurisdictions are always filed separately.  There is no *joint* filing; however you are expected to declare your spouse on your tax forms.

The primary reason to declare a spouse is to claim a *spousal amount* if that person has no (or very limited) income.

Some help about what a spouse is from the [Canada Revenue Agency](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/prsnl-nf/mrtl-eng.html) can basically be summarized as living together for a year, or that you have a child (natural or adoption) together.

If you had been living together for some time, then one passed away, for that given tax year, I expect you could claim some spousal amount.  But if there are deeper issues you need to clarify, then a visit to a tax lawyer would probably be worth the cost.